# Country based redirect only working for staging site not live site

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, country, wpml

I am trying to:
Make a redirect based on the IP of the visitor, i have my website hosted at wpengine and they have a GEO IP service from which i can get the users country based on their IP. If you are coming to the website from sweden,denmark or norway you will not be redirected but stay on page... http://www.centuri.se but if you are not from this countries you will be redirected to the english version of the site which is translated with wpml... so you will go to this page ... http://www.centuri.se/en/ which is the translated one.

I am using this piece of code to make the redirection.

```
<?php

// THE COOKIE NAME
$cookie_name = "country";

// ACCEPTED COUNTRIES THAT SKIPS THE REDIRECT
$countries = array('se','dk','no');

// CHECK IF YOUR COOKIE IS SET
if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {

  // GET USER INFO
$userInfo = do_shortcode('[geoip-country]');
// GET COUNTRY INTO LOWERCASE
$country = strtolower($userInfo);

//SET COOKIE BASED ON COUNTRY NAME FROM USER
setcookie('country', $country, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30), '/');

  if(!in_array($country, $countries)) {

      //Set a cookie to tell that this user has been redirected
      setcookie('redirect', 1, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30), '/');
      wp_redirect( home_url() . '/en/' ); exit;

  }

  }
  ?>
```

On my staging server from wpengine this sollution works flawless, you can test it for yourself http://centuri.staging.wpengine.com but when this script is applied for my live server i am redirected to http://www.centuri.se/en/en and will get an 404 message - i have tried to switch the part of the redirect from home_url() to site_url() instead to see any difference but if i do that on my live server this will give me a redirect loop. I have for now commented this out for my live site since it will make my website crash.

Could this be any setting done in WPML? i don't know really where to go from here... it's so confusing since it's works flawless on my staging server and not my live server and the code and databases are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested these but, here are a couple ideas:

1) You might just need to add a check for the current WPML language to make sure you aren't continuing to redirect the user once they are already on the EN site.

2) Your setting a `$_COOKIE['redirect']` but not doing anything with it. You could check that where you are checking the other cookie (I'm not sure the cookie will get set and be available immediately though if you are redirecting in a loop).

```
<?php
    // THE COOKIE NAME
    $cookie_name = "country";

    // ACCEPTED COUNTRIES THAT SKIPS THE REDIRECT
    $countries = array('se','dk','no');

    // CHECK IF YOUR COOKIE IS SET
    if (
        !isset( $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] )

        // Check redirect cookie??
        // && !isset( $_COOKIE['redirect'] )
    ) {

        // GET USER INFO
        $userInfo = do_shortcode('[geoip-country]');

        // GET COUNTRY INTO LOWERCASE
        $country = strtolower($userInfo);

        // SET COOKIE BASED ON COUNTRY NAME FROM USER
        setcookie('country', $country, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30), '/');

        if (
            // Don't redirect if current country is in skip list
            !in_array($country, $countries)

            // Also Check WPML lang code global to make sure the user
            // isn't already on the english site
            && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE !== 'en'
        ) {
          // Set a cookie to tell that this user has been redirected
          setcookie( 'redirect', 1, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30), '/' );
          wp_redirect( home_url() . '/en/' ); exit;
        }

    }
```

I just recently implemented the WPEngine GeoIP check myself, and another thing you might consider is using their PHP Class directly instead of `do_shortcode` (seems like that is probably working alright for you, but here is another method).

```
add_action( 'init', 'country_geo_redirect' );
function country_geo_redirect() {
    $geo = WPEngine\GeoIp::instance();
    $lang = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
    if (
        !is_admin() && // Let's not redirect the admin panel
        !in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) ) &&
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] !== 'example.com.au' && // Make sure we aren't already on this domain
        (
            strpos( strtolower( $lang ), 'en-au' ) > -1 // Check the user's browser languages for what we are targeting
            || $geo->country() == 'AU' // Fallback to using WPEngine's GeoIP Check if Browser lang doesn't include en-AU
        )
    ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://example.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

You have to keep in mind though, with using their class (`$geo = WPEngine\GeoIp::instance();`) it isn't able to determine the user's country unless it is run within an `init` action (if you run it directly in your functions.php file, `$country = $geo->country();` will return `NULL`).

With this second example, I'm also checking the user's browser languages first to see if it includes the target language (en-AU in this case) so that I might be able to skip the GeoIP lookup (in case there is any delay in that lookup) to improve loading speed (haven't actually tested that lookup time yet).